# How can I prevent a disabled AD user from logging in to a Linux server that has his public key?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, active-directory, powerbroker

I have a case on my Ubuntu Linux 16.04 servers that I need your help with:

**Current Scenario**

1. A valid AD user logs in to the Ubuntu Linux server via SSH
2. That user adds his public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for passwordless login
3. I disable/lock/delete the AD user to prevent him from logging in
4. The user was still able to login to the server, since his public key is still there!

**Expected Scenario:** If I disable/lock/delete a user's AD account (or his AD password expires), he shouldn't be able to login to any server with his AD account, even if his public key is installed there.

I have hundreds of servers, and it would be very difficult to track all the installed public keys.

Any solutions or workarounds for this without disabling PKI completely?

*Note:* I use PBIS Open to join my Linux servers to the AD domain.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add this to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password" "publickey,keyboard-interactive"

This will require public key and then will ask the user to enter his AD password.